# Deploy a subdirectory to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have one 'super' repository in GitHub which will contain several applications I would like to deploy to Heroku. Here is an example of my repository.

```
/app
  /.git
  /website <-- would like to deploy this to Heroku
```

When I try to push using the following command:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected.
```

How do I deploy a subdirectory to Heroku?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be accomplished by putting a config.ru in your root directory that tells Heroku where to find your app.  For example, with Rails 3, try a config.ru like this in your root directory:

```
WEBSITE_SUBDIR = 'website'
require "#{WEBSITE_SUBDIR}/config/environment"
run YourApplicationName::Application
```

And on Rails 2.x, you'll need something like this:

```
WEBSITE_SUBDIR = 'website'
require "#{WEBSITE_SUBDIR}/config/environment"
use Rails::Rack::LogTailer
use Rails::Rack::Static
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

Comment: Adam - thanks for your response. I have decided against deploying a full repo to heroku because I do not want to deploy the additional directories but this looks like a clean solution.

Comment: Jamie - the config.ru trick worked, until it came time to mirate the database, I couldn't figure out how to have my app in a subdir and get  the db to work.  Have you done both?  When I moved the app back to the top level it worked...

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.1.3 and this unfortunately didn't work for me, unless I made a mistake along the way?

Comment: Heroku can't necessarily update the database.yml for a non-standard location, so you'll need one that uses DATABASE_URL.  You can run a heroku console and print out the database.yml from a root level app to see how Heroku does it.  You'll also need to pay attention to where your Rakefile is and where it's loading from.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, at the end of the day I just put my Rails app into it's own repo

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git subtree` to push only your subfolder `website`:

```
git subtree push --prefix website heroku master
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about creating a local git repository in /app/website, and using [Git Hooks](http://benjamin-meyer.blogspot.com/2008/10/git-hooks.html) so that when you commit, it'll commit your website code as well?

The basic answer, from my perspective, is that you'll want a git repository at the website level, not a parent level. Everything from there depends on your point of view -- do you wan the /website to be its own repository with /app using a submodule  for /website? (That's the way I'd go)

Comment: Jesse, it seems from further research that having to create another repo is the only option. You could join the repos using submodules but what would be the point then.

If you have an example of using the web hooks option, that may be helpful to many.