# Rails application not in main directory, how to push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The person who made the project I'm working on forgot to put the Rails project contents in the main directory. Rather, the file structure is like this:

```
ProjectName
 ->/ProjectName
 ->/OtherStuff
```

..Where the second ProjectName directory is where the project actually lies. This is making it problematic for me to push this to Heroku. I did

```
$ heroku create --stack cedar
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:ProjectName.git
$ git push heroku master
```

from within the directory of the Rails project. But I get this error:

```
 !  No such app as ProjectName.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Which makes sense, since the application contents probably should be in the main directory. Problem is, I have no way to change this or contact the guy to have him change it at the moment, so is there any way for me to circumnavigate this problem?

EDIT:

I was able to change the 2nd directory's contents to the main file. But I'm still getting the same error. What's the problem here?

Comment: Similar question (and answer) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081699/deploy-a-subdirectory-to-heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you happy pushing OtherStuff up to Heroku?  As a git push pushes the entire repo up to Heroku it's probably worth splitting your repo up into chunks.

Whilst [Deploy a subdirectory to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081699/deploy-a-subdirectory-to-heroku) has a potential workaround, this would not sit well for me as I don't want to push non application assets to a host.

Comment: Yeah this is the approach I took in the end.